# How to collapse columns into row elements in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have data like this in pandas

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
print df

          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.945686  0.000710  0.909158  0.892892  0.326670
1  0.919359  0.667057  0.462478  0.008204  0.473096
2  0.976163  0.621712  0.208423  0.980471  0.048334
3  0.459039  0.788318  0.309892  0.100539  0.753992
```

Now i want to convert this to 2d data collapsing all column elements into single rows with labels and its index

```
0 a 0.160953  
0 b 0.945261  
0 c 0.979201  
0 d 0.099872  
0 e 0.247445
1 a 0.919359  
1 b 0.667057  
1 c 0.462478  
1 d 0.008204  
1 d 0.473096
...
...
3 e 0.753992
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.unstack()` will move the column labels into an index level.  If you want them as a column rather than an index level, you can do `df.unstack().reset_index()`.